# jquery change text once on change function

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem is that when i change the option it keeps summing, and i would like for it to only sum one time the value of 10.00, and subtract only once if the value is `AR` .

LIVE LINK: http://jsfiddle.net/A3qLG/1/

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $('#country').on('keyup change', function(e){

        var subt_value = $('#subt0').text();

        if($(this).val() == 'AR' || $(this).val() == ''){           
        if(subt_value != '0.00' ){$('#subt0').text(parseFloat(subt_value-10).toFixed(2));}      
        }else{          
        var add_sub = parseFloat(subt_value)+parseFloat('10.00');
        $('#subt0').text(parseFloat(add_sub).toFixed(2));
        }

    });

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<label id="subt0">8.90</label>

<select id="country">
  <option value="US">USA</option>
  <option value="BR">Brasil</option>
  <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
  <option value="CU">Cuba</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the HTML to this to store the original value:

```
<label id="subt0" data-original="8.90">8.90</label>
```

And then adjust the Javascript to this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $('#country').on('keyup change', function(e){

        //Changed the following line to get the original value      
        var subt_value = $('#subt0').attr('data-original');

        //Changed this to say, NOT AR and has a choice per the comments.            
        if($(this).val() != 'AR' && $(this).val().length > 0) {
          var add_sub = parseFloat(subt_value)+parseFloat('10.00');
          $('#subt0').text(parseFloat(add_sub).toFixed(2));
        } else {
          //Otherwise put it back to the original value
          $('#subt0').text(subt_value);
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: here is ur code online http://jsfiddle.net/A3qLG/4/ but there is a problem when i go back to the Argentina option i get `-1.10`

Comment: That's because 8.9 - 10 = -1.10.  You wanted it to subtract once, right?  If not, then you'll need to give some details about how your code should display results.

Comment: i made it subtract because country Argentina does not have a recharge all other country's must add $10 from the original price...so lets say the total order is $8.90 if i select any other country besides Argentina it should add $10 to the total... any thoughts of what can  i do to get that?

Comment: Yep, just convert what you typed into code.  I have edited that section in my answer.

Comment: Just made a correction by adding an else clause to restore the value in case it was changed.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $('#country').on('keypress change', function(e){

        var subt_value = $('#subt0').text();

        if($(this).val() == 'AR' || $(this).val() == ''){           
        if(subt_value != '0.00' ){$('#subt0').text(parseFloat(subt_value-10).toFixed(2));}      
        }else{          
        var add_sub = parseFloat(subt_value)+parseFloat('10.00');
        $('#subt0').text(parseFloat(add_sub).toFixed(2));
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: When submitting an answer, code by itself may solve the problem, but it doesn't give an answer.  Please explain your changes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember previous #country select value, and use it when making decision:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var prevValue = '';
    $('#country').on('keyup change', function (e) {
        var newValue = $(this).val();
        var subt_value = parseFloat($('#subt0').text());

        if ((newValue == 'AR' || newValue == '')) {
            if (prevValue != '' && prevValue != 'AR') {
                $('#subt0').text((subt_value - 10).toFixed(2));
            }
        } else {
            if (prevValue == 'AR' || prevValue == '') {
                $('#subt0').text((subt_value + 10).toFixed(2));
            }
        }
        prevValue = newValue;
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A3qLG/5/

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the onkeyup and onchange event handler functions after they have done their work.

```
$('#country').off('keyup change');
```

Comment: This was my first impression, too, but from the post saying to subtract only once... or add only once... I take it to be asking "each time the value is changed".

Comment: than instead of using an anonymous function in the handler, declare it as a named function.Wait a sec, I'll edit my post

Answer (score 0):

[Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/change/) provide a `.change()` specifically for `<select>`

You want to sum only one time and substract only one time base on the condition of the selected value `AR`. Therefore you only need to check the selected value if there is `change` and do the math within the `if-else` statement. Finally attach the result with `.toFixed(2)`

```
var subt_value = $('#subt0').text(); 
var add_sub = 0, f=10.00;
$('#country').change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() != 'AR'){
       add_sub = parseFloat(subt_value)+f;
    }else{
        add_sub = parseFloat(subt_value)-f;
    }

    $('#subt0').text(add_sub.toFixed(2));

});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/A3qLG/6/)